# ubercart cart "stacking"

Tags: drupal, ubercart

On my website, I use `hook_add_to_cart_data` to add some extra customization to items. When two identical products are added, but with different `$data`, it seems like ubercart squashes the old `$data` and stacks the items in the cart, updating `$qty` instead of adding a new item.

How can I tell ubercart to treat the new item and the old item as different items in the cart, so they don't get stacked, and can I otherwise control this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's shouldn't, see `uc_cart_get_contents` function in uc_cart.module, row #1358:

```
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($items[$cid]); $i++) {
    if ($items[$cid][$i]->nid == $item->nid && $items[$cid][$i]->data == $item->data) {
      $items[$cid][$i]->qty += $item->qty;
      continue 2;
    }
  }
```

One of reason: some other module merge (or clean) these $data for both products, before calling function `uc_cart_get_contents` in `uc_cart_add_item` function, in `hook_add_to_cart_data` implemention.